# Hide element on Firefox/IE and show only on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, input-type-file

I am using `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` to select folders on Chrome. While I know that this feature works only on Chrome, I would like to hide this button on browsers like Firefox and IE that don't support it.

I found a post that suggested to do something like the below code, however it returns false both on chrome and FF.

```
$scope.isDirSupp = function() {
    var tmpInput = $('#bulkyFolder');
    if ('webkitdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'mozdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'odirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'msdirectory' in tmpInput 
        || 'directory' in tmpInput) return true;

    return false;
}
```

html:
`<input type="file" webkitdirectory id="bulkyFolder" ng-show="isDirSupp">`

What is the best way to show this button on chrome and hide it on Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to show the input element only on Chrome.

```css
#bulkyFolder {
  display: none;
}
#bulkyFolder:not(*:root) { /* Supports only WebKit browsers */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory id="bulkyFolder" ng-show="isDirSupp">
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome :) Tagged this question as CSS as the accepted answer is related.

Answer (score 1):

Read [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

It has browser detection Technique, demo and way of doing it. 
He has explained to set the Boolean variable to true if it is a particular browser. So u can access it and display particular content on particular browsers alone.

Eg: `var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;`

This will set the variable `isChrome`

Now you can dynamically create the content in java script and display if `isChrome` is set.